# Enabling mouse support across different tmux versions

Tags: tmux

I manage several Linux machines, some with tmux version 2.1 in the repositories, and others with tmux versions less than 2.1. I use mouse mode, and I understand that in tmux 2.1, the option to enable mouse mode has changed to:

```
set -g mouse on
```

Since I use different distributions each with a different version of tmux, I wanted to make one .tmux.conf file that would enable the appropriate mouse option depending on the version.

So, I added the following to my .tmux.conf:

```
# Mouse Mode
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -ge 2.1 ]]" 'set -g mouse on'
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -lt 2.0 ]]" 'set -g mode-mouse on'
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -lt 2.0 ]]" 'set -g mouse-resize-pane on'
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -lt 2.0 ]]" 'set -g mouse-select-pane on'
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -lt 2.0 ]]" 'set -g mouse-select-window on'
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. tmux doesn't show any errors, but it also doesn't enable mouse mode either.

Is there some error in my logic which is preventing this configuration from working?

Answer (score 6):

Building on the last two answers but replacing the shell command as below. Add this to the main config:

```
if-shell "tmux -V |awk ' {split($2, ver, \".\"); if (ver[1] < 2) exit 1 ; else if (ver[1] == 2 && ver[2] < 1) exit 1 }' " 'source .tmux/gt_2.0.conf' 'source .tmux/lt_2.1.conf'
```

This uses awk to split the version number, a clearer version of this code is:

```
split($2, ver, ".")  #Split the second param and store it in the ver array
if ver[1] < 2) # if it's less than v2.0
   exit 1
else
   if (ver[1] == 2) # if it's version 2.n look at next number
       if (ver[2] < 1) # If the second number is less than 1 (2.1)
          exit 1
# else we exit 0
```

Then split the config out into the two config files.

`lt_2.1.conf` contains

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

`gt_2.1.conf` contains

```
set -g mouse-utf8 on
set -g mouse on
```

Comment: On version 1.8, `set-window-option -g mode-mouse on` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `set` is not a command of tmux and you can't execute it in `if-shell`.

I have an alternative scheme:

1. create two config files somewhere. Here we suppose that these two config files are `tmux_ge_21.conf` and `tmux_lt_21.conf`, they all locates at `~/.tmux/` directory.
2. Fill contents below to these two files:

For `tmux_ge_21.conf`:

```
set -g mouse-utf8 on
set -g mouse on
```

For `tmux_lt_21.conf`:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

3. add the line below in your `.tmux.conf`:

   ```
   if-shell "[[ `tmux -V | awk '{print ($2 >= 2.1)}'` -eq 1 ]]" 'source ~/.tmux/tmux_ge_21.conf' 'source ~/.tmux/tmux_lt_21.conf'
   ```
4. Execute `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` in your terminal.

---

BTW: For tmux which greater than 2.1, the default act of mouse scroll is changed. If you want it act as before, you have to install this tmux plug: https://github.com/nhdaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode

If you use this plugin, append `set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode'` to `tmux_ge_21.conf`.

---

BTW2: `-ge` in `` [[ `tmux -V |cut -d ' ' -f2` -ge 2.1 ]] `` seems work only when compare two integer number, I am not very sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I finally had a chance to give your idea a try. And while it was sound, it did not work. I ended up discovering that Debian has tmux 2.1 in backports, so I'm able to use a single .tmux.conf file for Arch and Debian. Ubuntu however, is still stuck on pre-2.1, so I suppose I'll either have to wait for 16.04 or compile from source.

Perhaps the code you posted can be reworked by someone else for a solution to someone else looking for a way around this issue.

Comment: @douglas-su: There seems to be a problem with `tmux -V | awk '{print ($2 >= 2.1)}'` as it does not correctly compare the version numbers: `tmux -V # => tmux 2.1` still when I run `tmux -V | awk '{print ($2 >= 2.9)}' # 1` the result equals 1 but should not.

Comment: The bigger problem is that `tmux -V | awk '{print ($2 >= 2.1)}'` is also true for tmux 2.0

Comment: Good solution, but I do not think that `It seems that set is not a command of tmux` is true. With the following configuration `if-shell "true" 'setw -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-select-window on; set -g mouse-select-pane on;'` the mouse mode is activated. (in tmux 2.0 and 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @douglas-su I found a solution which currently works (see caveat below).

Follow step 1 + 2 of his answer: create two files with options for < 2.1 and >= 2.1 options. Instead of step 3 insert the following snippet in your `.tmux.conf`:

`` if-shell "[[ `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed 's/[a\.]//g'` -ge 21 ]]" 'source ~/.tmux/tmux_ge_21.conf' 'source ~/.tmux/tmux_lt_21.conf' ``

Explanation:

- `cut -d ' ' -f2` selects the second part of `tmux -v`. Example: returns '2.1' for 'tmux 2.1'
- `sed 's/[a\.]//g'` replaces all dots `.` and `a`'s in the version string. Example: returns 19 for '1.9a'

Caveat: This solution probably does not work for all eternity but should work fine for all [releases of tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases) so far (current version is 2.1). If for any reason a updated older version would be released (e.g. 2.0.1 for a security fix or something similar) the proposed solution would no longer work as 201 >= 21.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that solution, but unfortunately, both files end up getting sourced and I see errors each time I start tmux.

Comment: Which version of tmux are you running? What is your output for `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed 's/[a\.]//g'`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @JayLaCroix. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas what the problem could be other than "Works on my machine" :-/